# Select 2 markup being inherited to next row

Tags: javascript

I have an application that loops though an array and outputs a series of select2 elements. There is a delete button next to each element. When one of these elements is deleted, there's a bug/glitch which means the previous select2 value is applied to the previous row.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3oqsmw0z/1/

I remove the item by index using `splice`:

```
deleteItem: function(index) {
    console.log('deleteItem');
    this.mySelects.splice(index, 1);
}
```

To replicate the issue:

Select the first option in the first select, the second option in the second select, then the third option in the third select. Now, delete the second option. In theory it should now show elements one and three (two has been deleted). But it show number two's option selected. You can see it's the third element by the label, and if you look at the markup in the console it is the third element. Why is it showing number two's selected option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using official [`Wrapper Component`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) for `select2`

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/skudrt3a/)**